# How to put javascript and html files from my master branch to the gh-pages branch?

Tags: git, github

I noticed some projects run their website on `xxx.github.io` subdomain. I liked that a lot and it seems to have a good position on google too. So I tried to start a test.

What happens is that GitHub creates new `gh-pages` branch on your repository:

[image: image description]

That contains the HTML files javascript files and images for your presentation. My project also contains scripts and images and I would like to make a demo of my project on the github page.

**The question is:** How to push the script files from `./` at my `master` branch to **`/scripts` subdirectory** on `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is your project a javascript library that you want to demo on the github pages?

Comment: @Francesco yes that exactly. I don't know how more exact can I be than: "*How to push the script files from ./ at my master branch to /scripts subdirectory on gh-pages branch.*" That's pretty direct request on help with repository operation.

Comment: What confuses me is that in the git environment `push` means to *Update remote refs along with associated objects* so you cannot push a file from a folder to another if that is not in a commit. Why don't you just copy the files from the master branch to the /script folder in the gh-pages branch, commit, push?

Comment: @Francesco How do I do that?

Comment: I assume you cloned the repo on your computer. from the master branch copy the files you need in a temp location, then checkout gh-pages and paste the files from the temp location. add, commit, push

Comment: Can I checkout every of these branches to different directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108523/discussion-between-francesco-and-tomas-zato).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gh-pages` branch is *orphaned*. This means that it is a completely separated branch from master without a common ancestor.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to clone the gh-pages branch to a new folder. In this way you can easily copy and paste the files you need to publish from master to gh-pages.

You can follow [this excellent post](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223)